# Consulta con dos tablas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer consultas SQL y necesito sacar el nombre del producto, su precio y el nombre de su fabricante del producto más barato. Estas son las tablas.

Tabla fabricante:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla productos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento lo que he conseguido hacer ha sido esto

```
(SELECT producto.nombre, producto.precio, fabricante.nombre AS fabricante 
 FROM producto, fabricante 
 WHERE producto.precio IN(SELECT MIN(precio) FROM producto);
```

Comment: Tienes que unir las dos tablas en la consulta sql usando inner join.

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask], ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: De momento lo que he conseguido hacer ha sido esto (SELECT producto.nombre, producto.precio, fabricante.nombre AS fabricante FROM producto, fabricante WHERE producto.precio IN(SELECT MIN(precio) FROM producto);

Comment: Entonces ¿ya consigues el resultado con dicha consulta o cual es la duda?

Comment: esta consulta me saca el nombre y el precio del producto mas bajo pero me lo repite 9 veces que son los nombres de fabricante y solo quiero que me salga una vez con su respectivo fabricante

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya que muestras tu consulta en los comentarios yo lo haría del siguiente modo:

- Selecciono todas las columnas que deseo mostrar de las 2 tablas
- Como existe una columna de llave foránea en la tabla productos que se liga con la de fabricante, entonces hago un `JOIN`
- Para solo mostrar los datos del producto mas barato hago una subconsulta estableciendo un `WHERE`
- Dentro de la subconsulta selecciono por medio de `MIN` el producto con el menor precio

Código

```
SELECT producto.nombre,
       producto.precio,
       fabricante.nombre
FROM fabricante
JOIN producto ON fabricante.codigo = producto.codigo_fabricante
WHERE producto.precio = (SELECT MIN(producto.precio) FROM producto);
```

Comment: Vale haciendo unas modificaciones esta consulta me ha servido. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si lo consideras prudente @Flaxx y los cambios son significativos puedes publicar tu respuesta para conocer dichos cambios

Comment: Nada, simplemente era cambiar los nombre de las tablas que en vez de productos era producto y cambiar fabricante.id por fabricante.codigo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Flaxx tienes razón ya modifiqué, la costumbre mia perdona